# How to read Unity Ads initialization code structure?

Tags: unity, c#, unity-ads

It is my first time integrating Unity ads into my game and my first time encountering the sample code below with the usage of "?" and ":"  and wanted to ask how to read the line of code below specifically the way it assigns the _gameId.

```
public void InitializeAds()
{
    _gameId = (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer)
        ? _iOSGameId
        : _androidGameId;

    Advertisement.Initialize(_gameId, _testMode, this); 
}
```

Comment: When you have questions about programming syntax, it's better to search our general programming sister site StackOverflow. [They'll already have answers to common questions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+is%3Aquestion+%22question+mark%22+colon). Ask here when you need help with topics that are specific to game development, not part of the C# language that's used for all kinds of non-game software too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code uses the [C# ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator).

This construct consists of three parts. A condition and two values.

```
<condition> ? <value_true> : <value_false>
```

When the condition is true, this construct returns the first value. When the condition is false, it returns the second value.

So what happens here is that the condition `Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer` is being evaluated. When it is true, then `_gameId` gets set to `_iOSGameId`. When it is false, then `_gameId` gets set to `_androidGameId`.

If you feel uncomfortable with ternary expression, then you could also write the whole method as this:

```
public void InitializeAds()
{
    if(Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer) 
    {
        _gameId = _iOSGameId;
    } 
    else 
    {
        _gameId = _androidGameId;
    }

    Advertisement.Initialize(_gameId, _testMode, this); 
}
```

What's immediately visible here is that any platform except iPhone is assumed to be Android. I am not familiar with the Unity ingame advertisement API, but this has some obvious code smell to me.

Comment: Now that makes sense. I'm used to using the structure you provided as the alternative and much readable to me. Thanks for this!